# Storing metadata in Google App Engine memcache using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

Is there a way to store and retrieve metadata along key-value pair in memcache in Google App Engine using Java?

I was trying to cache object with size more than 1MB in form of multiple 1MB segments and store number of segments in metadata.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: @MishaBrukman Edited question with what I was trying to implement. Still haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating special keys which use characters that otherwise don't appear in your regular keys, e.g., by appending a suffix to keys, such that they don't conflict with regular keys.

E.g., let's assume that your keys match the regex `[A-Za-z0-9]+`; then, you can take your key, e.g., `foobar42` and create special metadata key, e.g., `foobar42#metadata` which you know cannot be a valid key.

Then, when you store the key `foobar42` with some arbitrary value, you first create the key `foobar42#metadata` and store a special block there in, e.g., JSON or protocol buffer that says you can find the chunks of the value in `foobar42#chunk-0`, `foobar42#chunk-1`, etc.

Similarly when you lookup or delete the key, first see if there's a metadata key present, and if so, use additional logic to concatenate (if lookup) or delete the additional entries, so you don't leave stranded data occupying extra space.

Comment: @MishaBurkman Instead of special block you mentioned here, I stored total size along with actual data in memcache to figure out total number of chunks at run time. Followed similar naming convention. Thank  you for suggestion.